# Construcción de expresión regular en Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Estoy intentando construir una expresión regular para encontrar variables en ficheros fuente php. Me explico:
teniendo un fichero .php con este contenido:

```
$random = rand(0,getrandmax());
$dst    = substr(md5($random), 0, 1000000000);

function recurse_copy($src,$dst).....................
```

quiero obtener la posición dentro del fichero del inicio de $random = rand.... y la posición de $dst  = substr.....
Mi intención es extraer todas las asignaciones de variables del fichero para poder así tener una "colección" de todas las variables.
Por ejemplo: del anterior ejemplo, suponiendo que el primer carácter $ se corresponde con la posición 0, al lanzar la regex tendría que obtener un 0(que se corresponde con la primera asignación de variable) y otro número correspondiente al carácter $ donde comienza $dst    = ..... (la segunda asignación de variable).

La expresión regular sería algo como:
"que inicie con el carácter '$', que tenga cualquier número de caracteres/números hasta llegar a un caracter '=' ".

He intentado algunas construcciones pero obtengo None con todas ellas.
La última que he intentado, siguiendo algunos tutoriales y guías sobre Expresiones Regulares es:

```
p = re.compile('\$.*=')
pos = p.match(file_readed)
print(pos) #None
```

Pero obtengo None

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado o averiguado? Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve], explicando donde tienes problemas.

Comment: He intentado varias construcciones pero siempre obtengo un None como salida.
Lo último que he intentado es: p = re.compile('\$.*=')

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, no necesitas una expresión regular para esta tarea. Basta con saber usar métodos de cadena y listas. Saludos

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede. Es más, casi cualquier expresión regular se puede realizar mediante manipulación de cadenas. La idea de la expresión regular es no complicar algo que "ya está hecho". 
Cada persona pica su código de una manera diferente. Unos agregan espacios, otros incluso varios, otros ninguno, etc. Adecuar el código mediante manipulación de cadenas a esto es muy tedioso.

Comment: No he dicho que *no se puede*, he dicho que no es necesario usar expresiones regulares. Pero si quieres hacerlo con ellas, adelante.

Comment: Valdría la pena incluir en la pregunta un "script de prueba" para que todos podamos probar y validar resultados sobre un mismo archivo de prueba, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qué tal con este regex: `r'^\s*\$\w+\s*='`

Que empiece con cero (0) o más caracteres en blanco (espacio, tabulaciones, (indentación)), seguido del signo de `$`, seguido de *alfanumérico*, seguido de cero (0) o más espacios en blanco hasta encontrar un signo de `=`

Prueba:

```py
>>> regex = r'^\s*\$\w+\s*='
>>> print(re.search(regex, '$var = 12;')) # Variable normal
re.Match object; ...
>>> print(re.search(regex, '$var123 = 12;')) # Variable con nombre alfanum 
re.Match object; ...
>>> print(re.search(regex, '    $var    = 12;')) # Con indentación y espaciado
re.Match object; ...
>>> print(re.search(regex, '// $var = 12;')) # Variable comentada
None
>>> print(re.search(regex, 'function f1($var = null) {')) # Arg de funcion
None
>>>
>>> res = re.search(regex, '  $var123    = 12;')
>>> (res.group(0))[:-1].strip() # obteniendo el nombre de la variable
'$var123'
```

Ahora es cuestión de ir contabilizando las líneas que hacen match, en un `for` o `while`, iterando línea por línea en el documento.

Comment: Valdría la pena hacerle trim a eso por si hay espacios entre la variable y el signo igual, no? Lo otro, guiarse por la documentación pa ver el espacio de caracteres válidos para un nombre de variable.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Por alguna razón, sigo obteniendo None. Intentaré averiguar por qué, pero la regex es la que estaba intentando construir. De nuevo, mil gracias!!